# Move related products section before reviews in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I am working with woocommerce plugin. I currently have product, reviews and then it's related products in product detail page. I would like to change the display order. I want to display product, it's related products and then it's reviews. I have tried changing the priority in functions.php but it doesn't work. 
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The review section is located in woocommerce product tabs by default… The following code will move related products section before that product tabs:

```
add_action( 'init', 'move_related_products_before_tabs' );
function move_related_products_before_tabs( ) {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 5 );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to active theme's function.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 20 )

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 10 )
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 20 )
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work :( I may have to try your code's variations.